# Probability inequality exchanging sum with cardinality

Tags: probability

Let $P_{XY}$ be the joint probability distribution of discrete random variables $X$, $Y$. Then I would like to prove the following inequality:

$$
\sum_{y}\max_xP_{XY}(x,y)\leq |Y|\max_xP_X(x)
$$

where $P_X$ is the marginal distribution of random variable $X$ and $|Y|$ is the cardinality of random variable $Y$. Hints are also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $P_{XY}(x,y) = P_X(x) \cdot P_{Y \mid X=x}(y) \le P_X(x)$